# Firebase Firestore database taking too long to update field

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update certain fields in a list of sorted documents in Firebase Firestore. I'm a beginner so I hope I can get your feedback on how to optimize the code below. Currently it takes over 5 seconds for this function to fully execute.

```
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await events.get();
  var compareWith = DateTime.now();
  var Data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) {
    var eventDate = DateTime(doc.get('Year'), doc.get('Month'), doc.get('Day'),
        doc.get('Hour'), doc.get('Minute'));
    var difference = eventDate.difference(compareWith).inMinutes;
    return events
        .doc('${doc.id}')
        .update({'MinutesLeft': difference})
        .then((value) => print("Event Created"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update event: $error"));
  }).toList();
```

Comment: You're currently fetching all events without querying anything. I assume you want only events that are not past events, right? (According to the "MinutesLeft" you're updating). I'd suggest changing the year/month/day/hour/minute to a timestamp and then querying for events where the timestamp is larger the the current time. Also I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do... MinutesLeft is something that should be calculated in the client and not saved on the db

Comment: What makes you say that 5 seconds is too long? How many documents are you retrieving in `events.get()`? How big are they? What is the bandwidth of the device on which you run this code?

Comment: @IncrediApp I'm updating the values in the database before it is queried and displayed to the user. So I need to write to the database and update the MinutesLeft. Do you suggest a different way of doing this?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm only fetching about 15 documents. Phone has a download speed of 100 mbps.

Comment: As pointed out by @IncrediApp, I would first change your year/month/etc. to a [`timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp).

Also, this [article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/08/why-is-my-cloud-firestore-query-slow.html) might be helpful understanding why a Cloud Firestore query is slow, also explained on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQRIVztNSMQ&t=242s)